# Executing angularJS code which has been received as string in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, dom

My use case is that am receiving a form template as a string and also its behavior (the angular code) as strings in my controller. Now I am passing them into my custom directive. What I want is to paint that template in DOM and execute the code inside the string. Both of these have been achieved. What I am not able to do is to bind data in angular way, although the code in behavior string is registered to scope. Let me explain it step by step -

My parent template is temp.html:

```
<ngc-formmaker formhtml="fetchBillForm" formbehaviour="behaviour"></ngc-formmaker>
```

My parent controller is something like this:

```
.controller('fetchFormController', ['$scope', 'formElement', function($scope, formElement){
    console.log("inside controller");
    console.log(formElement);
    $scope.fetchBillForm = formElement.formString;
    $scope.behaviour = formElement.behaviour;
    // $scope.$apply();
}]);
```

Here formElement is as service that returns an object with two properties - formString and behaviour. This formString contains the template for form as string and behaviour is code corresponding to form's validation, some logic over dropdowns/select-box/etc. This 'behaviour' is also a string.

My directive is used to show this template and its function is to bind the behaviour of this template into scope. Directive is:

```
angular.module('ngcFormmaker', [])
.directive('ngcFormmaker', ['$compile','$timeout',function($compile, $timeout){
    return{
        restrict : 'AE',
        transclude : true,
        replace : true,
        link : function(scope, element, attrs){
            //bind the template
            element.html(scope.$eval(attrs.formhtml));
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            //bind the behaviour
            if(attrs.formbehaviour){
                 var stringifiedJS = scope.$eval(attrs.formbehaviour);
                 //scope.$eval(stringifiedJS);
                 eval(stringifiedJS);
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Little description of behaviour string-
The 'behaviour' string already has variables defined. one example could be - scope.showFormSubmit = true;. This scope variable is used in template to ng-show submit button. This behaviour string also has blocks defined, such as - if(scope.form.dropdown.$viewValue == 'no'){scope.showFormSubmit = false;}.   In a similar way there are functions defined in this too. And everything as string.

Because of functions and ifs, I cant use scope.$eval of angular, it throws error. So I used eval of javascript.

My issue:
The scope variables of the template are binded once. But only once at the start. I can say this as they show the submit button at starting, but after selecting wrong option from dropdown they dont hide the submit button. Actually every variable in my model/scope is binded and changes value as selected in dropdown, but just the code inside if-elses doesn't execute.

What I expect as answer:
Correct way of doing this, which might be changing the current approach or just solving the problem according to this approach.